# Passing Parameters to and from procedures

Tags: c++, parameters

I'm currently making a very basic program (yes, i'm a novice) and i'm having trouble with passing parameters to and from procedures.

```
void processAPrice();
void getPriceInPounds(priceInPounds);
void convertPriceIntoEuros(int priceInPounds);
void showPriceInEuros();
void calculateSum();
void produceFinalData();


int main()                  
{
    char answer('Y');
    int numberOfPrices(0);

    while (answer = 'Y')
    {
        processAPrice();
        numberOfPrices++;
        cout << "Continue? (Y/N)";
        cin >> answer;
    }

    if (numberOfPrices > 0)
        produceFinalData();


    system("PAUSE");    //hold the screen until a key is pressed
    return(0);
}


void processAPrice()    //
{
    getPriceInPounds(priceInPounds);
    convertPriceIntoEuros(priceInPounds);
    showPriceInEuros();
    calculateSum();
}

void getPriceInPounds(int priceInPounds)        //
{
    int priceInPounds;
    cout << "Enter a price (in Pounds): /234";
    cin >> priceInPounds;

}


void convertPriceIntoEuros(int priceInPounds)   //
{
    const int conversionRate(0.82);
    int priceInEuros = (priceInPounds / conversionRate);
```

On the processAPrice procedure, I am calling getPriceInPounds procedure but I keep getting an error saying that priceInPounds is an undeclared identifier. I presume this is because I've got it in the parameters in the processAPrice procedure but if I take it out, surely I won't be able to pass the priceInPounds variable back to the processAPrice?

Could anyone possibly explain how to correctly do this?
Basically I need it so that the variable priceInPounds is passed back to processAPrice so that I can then pass the same variable to convertPriceIntoEuros.

Thanks :)

I'm using VS13 and c++ btw!

Comment: I would have no good answer - but - you might start thinking in functions taking arguments and returning a value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are missing the type of the parameter in the function declaration. You need

```
void getPriceInPounds(int priceInPounds);
                      ^^^
```

On the other hand, that function does not need a parameter at all, because you don't use it. It seems to me you want to input the price, and return it back to the caller. In this case, your function could look like this:

```
int getPriceInPounds()
{
    int priceInPounds;
    cout << "Enter a price (in Pounds): /234";
    cin >> priceInPounds;
    return priceInPounds;
}

int convertPriceIntoEuros(int priceInPounds)   //
{
  const int conversionRate(0.82);
  return priceInPounds / conversionRate;
}
```

And you would call it like this:

```
int pounds = getPriceInPounds();
int euros = convertPriceIntoEuros(pounds);
```

and so on.

Comment: Ahh thank you, so from this I understand that "return priceInPounds" will pass the variable priceInPounds back to the calling function, which in my case will pass it to processAPrice which I can then pass to the other functions via parameters?

Comment: @Craig You would use it like this: `int price = getPriceInPoinds();`, then you can pass `price` to other functions.